# Showing this a norm

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I want to show that $$\| x \| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{\left| x_n \right|}{1+\left| x_n \right|}$$ is a norm. I'm fine showing positivity and the triangle inequality, to show the second property however
$$\| \lambda x \| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} \frac{\left| \lambda x_n \right|}{1+\left| \lambda x_n \right|} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{\left| \lambda \right| \left| x_n \right|}{1+\left| \lambda \right| \left| x_n \right|} .... $$ Where do we go from here?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a norm. In fact, it is only a F-norm. It is usually defined in a Fréchet space. And it is always defined by using a series of semi-norms. I am not sure what it is called formally. But I call it F-norm.

Comment: If you can expand your answer little bit more, that would be better.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a norm. Consider $x=(1,0,0,0,\ldots)$ and some $|\lambda| \neq 1$

For e.g. $\lambda = 2$ we get $$||\lambda x|| = \frac{|\lambda|}{2(1+|\lambda|)} = \frac{1}{3}$$

but on the other hand

$$|\lambda|||x|| = 2 \frac{1}{2(1+1)} = \frac{1}{2}$$